# Access value in method sent by parent::__construct()

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I'm having trouble getting the value passed via parent__construct in a Controller's child class and using that value in a class called View.

When performing a var_dump in the __Construct of the Controller class I can retrieve the value sent from the Form class, but when I try to retrieve this same value in a METHOD inside the View class, it appears as null.

Could you help me with this problem?

Here are the codes:

```
============================================
class Form extends Controller
{
    //General builder of the WEB pages
    public function __construct()
    {
        //Redirecting the entire site for maintenance
        //redirect("/ops/maintenance");

        parent::__construct(__DIR__ . "/../../../themes/" . THEME . "/pages/");
    }
}
============================================
class controller
{
    /** @var View */
    protected $view;

    /** @var Message */
    protected $message;

    //Builder extending classes
    /**
     * Controller constructor
     * @param string|null $pathToViews
     */
    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->view = new View($pathToViews);
        //the value passed in parent::__construct() appears here
        var_dump($pathToViews);
        $this->message = new Message();
    }
}
============================================

//Class responsible for handling Views requests
class view
{
    protected $pathToViews;

    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->pathToViews = $pathToViews;
    }

    //Function to Load the View and send content from the backend to the frontend
    public function show($viewName, $data = [])
    {
        var_dump($this->pathToViews);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving you error or warning in View?
Can you try commenting out protected $pathToViews: in View class?

Comment: @Vantiya

No error occurs, what happens is that I can't get the value passed in the parent::__construct() of the Form child class.

I want to get this value from the View class inside the show() method, but when I give $this->pathToViews inside the show() it returns null

Comment: I updated my answer. Going from your responses, you're getting a null value because you're making a new instance of the view class.

Comment: what do you mean it appears as null? it does not appear as null in my case, the value from the form constructor is passed to the view object. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Douma

I want to access the value of parent::__construct(__DIR__ . "/../../../themes/" . THEME . "/pages/") inside the show() method of the View Class without having to pass it by the instance.

Comment: @Douma

I know it arrives at the Controller because of var_dump($pathToViews) in the Controller's __construct, and I pass $this->view = new View($pathToViews) to send the value to the View class, but I can't access the value from $pathToViews inside the show() method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**:

If you don't want to call the show method in the controller class, but you want to instantiate that class in your controller class you should find a way to get the view class accessible outside of your controller class. Just instantiating view class again outside of the controller is another instance and will indeed show a null value on the $pathToViews variable.

One way of doing this is like this:

```
    class controller
{
    /** @var View */
    protected $view;


    //Builder extending classes
    /**
     * Controller constructor
     * @param string|null $pathToViews
     */
    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->view = new View($pathToViews);


        var_dump($pathToViews);
    }

    public function getView() : View
    {
        return $this->view;
    }
}



//Class responsible for handling Views requests
class View
{
    protected $pathToViews;

    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->pathToViews = $pathToViews;

        echo $this->pathToViews;
    }

    //Function to Load the View and send content from the backend to the frontend
    public function show($viewName, $data = [])
    {
        var_dump($this->pathToViews);
    }
}

$controller = new controller('testString');
$view = $controller->getView();

$view->show('test');
```

Another way of doing this is using the principle of dependency inversion

```
    class controller
{
    /** @var View */
    protected $view;


    //Builder extending classes
    /**
     * Controller constructor
     * @param View $view
     * @param string|null $pathToViews
     */
    public function __construct(View $view, string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->view->setPathtoViews($pathToViews);


        var_dump($pathToViews);
    }

    public function getView() : View
    {
        return $this->view;
    }
}



//Class responsible for handling Views requests
class View
{
    protected $pathToViews;


    public function setPathtoViews(string $pathToViews)
    {
        $this->pathToViews = $pathToViews;
    }

    //Function to Load the View and send content from the backend to the frontend
    public function show($viewName, $data = [])
    {
        var_dump($this->pathToViews);
    }
}

$view = new View();
$controller = new controller($view, 'testString');

$view->show('test');
?>
```

**Original answer**
Your code runs fine on my machine. I have run the code block below. What I did change to make it work was actually calling $this->view->show(). In your code example that wasn't the case.

As a small note. I know php is case insensitive but as a good practice call your classes with the same casing as how you defined them (view vs View).

```
<?php

class controller
{
    /** @var View */
    protected $view;


    //Builder extending classes
    /**
     * Controller constructor
     * @param string|null $pathToViews
     */
    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->view = new View($pathToViews);

        $this->view->show('test');

        var_dump($pathToViews);
    }
}



//Class responsible for handling Views requests
class View
{
    protected $pathToViews;

    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
    {
        $this->pathToViews = $pathToViews;

        echo $this->pathToViews;
    }

    //Function to Load the View and send content from the backend to the frontend
    public function show($viewName, $data = [])
    {
        var_dump($this->pathToViews);
    }
}

$controller = new controller('testString');
?>
```

Comment: This way I'm forced to pass the parameters $viewName, $data = [] through the Controller class, and this can cause problems in other parts of the code, because my View class receives these parameters from other controllers, which I need and I can't do and take the value passed in the parent::__construct() of the Form controller and use it inside the show() method, but when I give a $this->pathToViews inside the show() it returns null

Comment: Does my update help you along?

Comment: It didn't help me correctly, because of the removal of the parent::__construct() snippet inside the __construct() of the Form child class

See if I'm right, the modes you entered, I would need to send the value of $pathToViews every time I instantiate the View class right?

Comment: And for my tests I only need to pass the value once that will be used in $pathToViews when I enter it in parent::__construct(), but I can't retrieve this value inside the show() method, it loads null, and as you said , it's because I re-instantiate the View() class on the Form() right? isn't there a way to automate this using the parent::__construct() feature? Because in your mode I would have to pass this value from $pathToViews every time I call the right method?

Comment: Everytime you create a new instance of the view class you need to set the $pathToViews property. That's correct.

Comment: Of course you can always add the constructor (i removed it because it was empty, sorry for making it a bit more complicated) 

`class View {
    protected $pathToViews;

    public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null) {
     $this->setPathtoViews($pathToViews);
    }

    public function setPathtoViews(string $pathToViews) {
        $this->pathToViews = $pathToViews;
    }

    public function show($viewName, $data = []) {
        var_dump($this->pathToViews);
    }
}`